# Телеграм бот на вебхука

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не понимаю как перевести телеграм бота на вебхуки. Создал SSL сертификат и ключ, но не могу понять откуда взять **HOST**, как посмотреть статус (типа iptables на Linux, только мне надо Windows), как настроить webhook и как вот это записать в cmd `lsof -i | grep python3.6`

```
import telebot

import cherrypy
import logging

WEBHOOK_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
WEBHOOK_PORT = 443  # 443, 80, 88, 8443
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = 'C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/telegram_bot/server.crt'  # certificate path
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = 'C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/telegram_bot/server.key'

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % ('TokenBot')

logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class WebhookServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        if 'content-length' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                'content-type' in cherrypy.request.headers and \
                cherrypy.request.headers['content-type'] == 'application/json':
            length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['content-length'])
            json_string = cherrypy.request.body.read(length).decode("utf-8")
            update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)

            bot.process_new_updates([update])
            return ''
        else:
            raise cherrypy.HTTPError(403)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TokenBot')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def getstart(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Привет")


bot.remove_webhook()
access_log = cherrypy.log.access_log


bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))
for handler in tuple(access_log.handlers):
    access_log.removeHandler(handler)
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
    'server.socket_port': WEBHOOK_PORT,
    'server.ssl_module': 'builtin',
    'server.ssl_certificate': WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT,
    'server.ssl_private_key': WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV
})
cherrypy.quickstart(WebhookServer(), WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, {'/': {}})
```

Пробовал через команду `setWebhook` от Телеграм, но оно не дало результато. Также пробовал через запуск в фоновом режиме, но через pooling, оно начинает долго отвечать

Answer (score 1):

Когда столкнулся с вопросом деплоя вебхуков, то использовал бесплатный хостинг https://www.pythonanywhere.com c таким кодом:

```
import telebot # pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
from config import TOKEN, SECRET, URL #URL = "https://nameofmysite.pythonanywhere.com/"
from flask import Flask, request, abort

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, threaded=False)
bot.remove_webhook()
url = URL + SECRET
bot.set_webhook(url = url)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/{}'.format(SECRET), methods=["POST"])
def telegram_webhook():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        # json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        json_string = request.stream.read().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return 'ok', 200
    else:
        abort(403)
# код программы
# ...
# код программы


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello!'
```

На сайте pythonanywhere.com веб приложение делается в три клика: `WEB` -> `Add a new web app` -> `Flask`, в результате генериться файл `flask_app.py`. В этот файл нужно записать приведенный код, заменив все его содержание.

Comment: а что означать SECRET, случаной не методы типа get_Update и т.д? И если да, то мне туда надо подставить setwebhook? И URL какой именно надо?

Comment: secret  = любое выражение (любая фраза, например, SECRET = "jhkjh-777h-kjhkjh-iuoiu", она такая же секретная, как и токен), url - это ссылка, которую создает pythonanywhere на бесплатном тарифе, для платных, вроде, есть возможность использовать свое доменное имя.